# Add a button to a Google Calendar Event View on Web

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

Hopefully this is quite simple. Requirements is as follows:

When looking at an event within Google Calendar (Web), I want to add a button / link that redirects to a custom domain with the event id. From there I have the Google API setup so I can pull through all the event data but I need to trigger this process with the event ID.

The flow is as follows:

```
User creates event in Google Calendar =>
User views the event in Google Calendar =>
There is a button saying "Create event in XXX system" =>
They click the button =>
They are redirected to the new site with the event id in the query-string =>
The new sites authenticates the user and requests Google Calendar Permissions =>
The new site pulls the event data from Google Calendar using the API and ID provided
```

Possible to embed this in Google Calendar?

Thanks in advance